# how to make the tabs from tab-bar-mode always stay on the same line?

Tags: tabbar

I don't know if there is a better title, but this is the one that's most verbose (a less verbose one would have been "how to make the tabs overflow to the left side" or something along those lines)

This is related to another question I asked, [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78913/how-to-prevent-tabs-from-shrinking-when-using-many-tabs-with-tab-bar-mode). The goal is to have the tabs not taking "multiple lines" (when there is a lot of tabs), as can be seen on [this image](https://i.imgur.com/tjjpFv2.png) and instead be on the same [line](https://i.imgur.com/urZ99CE.png).

Is there a way to do this in Elisp?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the tabs always stay on the same line, then you need to enable this setting:

```elisp
(setq tab-bar-auto-width t)
```

When the large number of tabs causes tab shrinking too much, then you can split tabs to tab groups by customizing `tab-bar-format` where `tab-bar-format-tabs` should be replaced with `tab-bar-format-tabs-groups`.  Then you can use `C-x t G` to move the current tab to a group.